# How to handle content of address by pointer if address is kown, without trigger segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

I am learning C and I want to access(just to see what is inside the address, for fun actually.) content in specific address in C like:

```
char *p = (char *)0x7ffeefad7be8;
printf("%s",*p);
```

but it show segmentation fault. I know that part of memory is 
reserved and can not be access, the space for kernal, e,g. But I think that the address is accessable since it is the address which I got from this code:

```
int *p,a;
p = &a;
printf("%p",p);
```

So it is suppose to be inside range of [heap] and [stack].(It is separated with the first code and just proved the address is accessable)

But the error just keep reporting! I did a lot of trying and researching, though it still doesn't work.

Here is the output of `$cat /proc/self/maps`:

00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 3942120                            /usr/bin/cat

0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 08:09 3942120                            /usr/bin/cat

0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:09 3942120                            /usr/bin/cat

01a4f000-01a70000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]

7f960e06f000-7f960e23b000 r--p 00000000 08:09 3969887                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive

7f960e23b000-7f960e3d2000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 3935387                    /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so

7f960e3d2000-7f960e5d2000 ---p 00197000 08:09 3935387                    /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so

7f960e5d2000-7f960e5d6000 r--p 00197000 08:09 3935387                    /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so

7f960e5d6000-7f960e5d8000 rw-p 0019b000 08:09 3935387                    /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so

7f960e5d8000-7f960e5dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f960e5dc000-7f960e5ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 3935386                    /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so

7f960e7ba000-7f960e7bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f960e7dd000-7f960e7ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f960e7ff000-7f960e800000 r--p 00023000 08:09 3935386                    /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so

7f960e800000-7f960e801000 rw-p 00024000 08:09 3935386                    /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so

7f960e801000-7f960e802000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff58c4c000-7fff58c6d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]

7fff58d0e000-7fff58d11000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]

7fff58d11000-7fff58d13000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]

ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

I really want to figure out why it doesn't work because i have spent hours on trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is not from accessing the address `p` points add directly. Rather, you want to print the ASCIIZ string pointed to by `p` and that means that `printf` will (try to) access memory from there up until the first NUL byte encountered. It may well be that no NUL occurs until the end of the allowed data segment.
If you first assign `a=0` then the first byt e`p`points at should alreday be NUL and no fault should be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `p` has type `char *`, meaning it is a pointer which is believed to point to a `char`.

In the second argument to `printf()`, you dereference `p`. Thus, the second argument to `printf()` is actually some single byte value. Since the format specifier being used is `%s`, the second argument to `printf()` is expected to be a `char *`, and is used to read the string beginning at that location.

Thus, the singly byte value obtained from dereferencing `p` is being treated as an address and being dereferenced. Therefore, the segmentation fault occurs because of an attempt to access a restricted memory address, potentially 0x0 i.e. null.

On a further note, I don't think the cast `(* char)` is valid. To cast to a `char *`, you should use `(char *)`. In this case, it is not necessary to explicitly cast to a `char *` and the cast is optional.

Comment: yeah, it suppose to be (char *):D

Comment: I changed the format specifier into `%c` but it doesn't work. I also tried (int *) and `%d` still not work. each time the error report is different like `[1]    10163 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
` or `[1]    10092 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
`, with no more information provided.

Comment: What you need to change is the second argument. It should be `p` rather than `*p`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access [...] content in specific address in C like:
>
> ```
> char *p = (* char)0x7ffeefad7be8;
> printf("%s",*p);
> ```
>
> but it show segmentation fault.

As other answers already observe, the `printf()` argument corresponding to a `%s` field descriptor is expected to be a `char *`.  That would be `p`, not `*p`.  The latter is the `char` to which `p` points.

But that's pretty much a minor syntax error, and you have much larger semantic issues with your code.  C provides that an integer may be converted to any pointer type, but except for a in couple of narrow cases, the result is implementation defined.  In particular, C in no way requires that converting the numeric value of a machine address (whether physical or virtual) results in a pointer to whatever resides at that address.

*Even if* your implementation behaves as you seem to expect with respect to integer-to-pointer conversions, your subsequent comment still exhibits a misapprehension:

> But I think that the address is accessable since it is the address which I got from this code [...]. So it is suppose to be inside range of [heap] and [stack].

Just because the address is accessible during one run of one program in no way means it is accessible even during a different run of the same program, much less during a run of an altogether different program.  Modern operating systems do not allow processes to access memory willy-nilly.  Each process has specific virtual address ranges assigned to it, and these are not guaranteed to be the same from one run to another or from one program to another.

**Bottom line**: what you are trying to do is inherently implementation-dependent and generally unlikely to yield any useful result.  You cannot safely examine random locations in memory.

Comment: I don't disagree with your point, but the question is not asking whether this is advisable or production-appropriate. On the contrary, it is stated that this is "just to see what is inside the address, for fun actually". For someone learning C and learning about computer systems, this seems like a reasonable exercise in trying to better understand the underlying system and reconcile that understanding with an uncovered anomaly.

Comment: @fvargas, learning what you cannot and/or should not do, and why, is at least as important to learning about programming and computer systems as is learning what you *can* do.  It is reasonable for a neophyte to be curious and to try such a thing as the OP did -- I did not say anything to the contrary -- but when they ask why it did not produce the hoped-for results, I don't see why we should not explain why such an experiment cannot be *expected* to produce reasonable results.  How is that *not* what they want to know?